# mi servidor Apache-2.4.33 + PHP 8.1 + W10 permite header DESPUÉS de haber output, cómo puedo corregirlo?

Tags: php

todos ustedes sáben que ésto debe dar un error:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

echo '123';
header('Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

pues mi servidor no lo háce y me ha dádo ya muchos problemas cuando súbo los archivos al servidor REMOTO LINUX

qué debo corregir en mi **php.ini** ?
es un error en mi **httpd.conf** ?

gracias

Comment: Quita el `ini_set()` e intenta con `error_reporting(E_ALL)`.

Comment: Con respecto al problema planteado aquí, ¿qué configuraciones tienes en tu `php.ini` y en tu `httpd.conf`? ¿Tampoco hay errores o advertencias en el log de errores?

Comment: gracias, ya he colocado `error_reporting(E_ALL);` y continúa SIN mostrar error. LOG de Apache y PHP 0 registros.